# Any better way to set and get from LocalStorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, local-storage

I am trying to figure out a better way to do what my code down below does..
What it does is that it save a timestamp in localstorage to know when that link was last clicked, and then it appears when the time runs out. But it will be alot of copy paste if I want to add some more links... 
Can someone help me how to loop trough the "save and load" script? And maybe add the amount of minutes to count in the link instead of in the script?

This is how I did it now:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="checkLocalStorage()">
   <a onclick="saveTime01()" id="linkID01" href="#">Link1</a>
   <a onclick="saveTime02()" id="linkID02" href="#">Link2</a>
   <a onclick="saveTime03()" id="linkID03" href="#">Link3</a>
   <a onclick="saveTime04()" id="linkID04" href="#">Link4</a>
</body>
</html>
```

in my script.js

```
function checkLocalStorage() {
    setInterval(function(){
        if("linkValue01" in localStorage){
            var storedTime = localStorage.getItem("linkValue01");
            var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
            var minutesFromLastClick = (timeNow - storedTime)/60000;
            if(minutesFromLastClick > 30) {
                document.getElementById("linkID01").style.display = "inline";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("linkID01").style.display = "none";
            }
        }
        if("linkValue02" in localStorage){
            var storedTime = localStorage.getItem("linkValue02");
            var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
            var minutesFromLastClick = (timeNow - storedTime)/60000;
            if(minutesFromLastClick > 180) {
                document.getElementById("linkID02").style.display = "inline";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("linkID02").style.display = "none";
            }
    }
    if("linkValue03" in localStorage){
            var storedTime = localStorage.getItem("linkValue03");
            var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
            var minutesFromLastClick = (timeNow - storedTime)/60000;
            if(minutesFromLastClick > 120) {
                document.getElementById("linkID03").style.display = "inline";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("linkID03").style.display = "none";
            }
    }
    if("linkValue04" in localStorage){
            var storedTime = localStorage.getItem("linkValue04");
            var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
            var minutesFromLastClick = (timeNow - storedTime)/60000;
            if(minutesFromLastClick > 10) {
                document.getElementById("linkID04").style.display = "inline";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById("linkID04").style.display = "none";
            }
    }
    }, 1000);
}


function saveTime01(){
    var object = new Date().getTime();
    localStorage.setItem("linkValue01", JSON.stringify(object));
    document.getElementById("linkID01").style.display = "none";
}
function saveTime02(){
    var object = new Date().getTime();
    localStorage.setItem("linkValue02", JSON.stringify(object));
    document.getElementById("linkID02").style.display = "none";
}
function saveTime03(){
    var object = new Date().getTime();
    localStorage.setItem("linkValue03", JSON.stringify(object));
    document.getElementById("linkID03").style.display = "none";
}
function saveTime04(){
    var object = new Date().getTime();
    localStorage.setItem("linkValue04", JSON.stringify(object));
    document.getElementById("linkID04").style.display = "none";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could do this -

```
  <a class="tracker" id="linkValue1" data-id="1" href="#">Link1</a>
  <a class="tracker" id="linkValue2" data-id="2" href="#">Link2</a>
  <a class="tracker" id="linkValue3" data-id="3" href="#">Link3</a>
  <a class="tracker" id="linkValue4" data-id="4" href="#">Link4</a>
```

Now in Javascript -

```
 $(".tracker").on("click",handleClick);

 function handleClick(){
     var ele = $(this),
         object = new Date().getTime(),
         id = ele.data("id"); 

     localStorage.setItem("linkValue"+id, JSON.stringify(object));
     document.getElementById("linkID"+id).style.display = "none";
  }

 function checkLocalStorage() {
      var numLinks = $(".tracker").length;
      setInterval(function(){
         for(var i = 0; i< numLinks.length;++i){
              var item = "linkValue"+numLinks[i],
                  eleID = "linkID"+numLinks[i];
              if(item in localStorage){
                   var storedTime = localStorage.getItem(item);
                   var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
                   var minutesFromLastClick = (timeNow - storedTime)/60000;
                   if(minutesFromLastClick > 30) {
                      document.getElementById(eleID).style.display = "inline";
                  }
                  else {
                       document.getElementById(eleID).style.display = "none";
                  }
               }
            }
         }
    }
```

Comment: Can't find jquery tag in question.

Comment: Since it was not mentioned, I used jquery :) Same logic can be added for javascript as well. The optimization remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid multiple functions using *one function with different arguments*. In `interval`, writing `for-loop` can reduce many lines of code and will also make your code readable..

```js
function checkLocalStorage() {
  setInterval(function() {
    for (var i = 1, iLen = 4; i <= iLen; i++) {
      if ("linkValue0" + i in localStorage) {
        var storedTime = localStorage.getItem("linkValue0" + i);
        var timeNow = new Date().getTime();
        var minutesFromLastClick = (timeNow - storedTime) / 60000;
        if (minutesFromLastClick > 30) {
          document.getElementById("linkID0" + i).style.display = "inline";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("linkID0" + i).style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    }
  }, 1000);
}


function saveTime(key, id) {
  var object = new Date().getTime();
  localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(object));
  document.getElementById(id).style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<body onload="checkLocalStorage()">
  <a onclick="saveTime('linkValue01',this.id)" id="linkID01" href="#">Link1</a>
  <a onclick="saveTime('linkValue02',this.id)" id="linkID02" href="#">Link2</a>
  <a onclick="saveTime('linkValue03',this.id)" id="linkID03" href="#">Link3</a>
  <a onclick="saveTime('linkValue04',this.id)" id="linkID04" href="#">Link4</a>
</body>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/4mkuty3p/)

Comment: Wow, super fast answers! But this code does reset all 4 links at the same time, right?

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for, but sorry if im stupid, been awake for a while now.. But where do I set the individual time for the links to appear again? In my example link 1 is 30 minutes, link 2 180 minutes etc... Could I set those values in the link?

Comment: ok, I will try to do that, im pretty noob in programming, Would you mind writing an example or fiddle?

Comment: The more I try the more confused I get... can someone please have a look at this fiddle and help me out.. https://jsfiddle.net/4mkuty3p/90/

Comment: Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/4mkuty3p/156/ You have changed the ids of the elements and you were trying with different ids in the js..